# How to properly set up the Backbone.js urlRoot method

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am having trouble understanding how `urlRoot` works in Backbone.js. I am attempting to fetch a task with a specific `_id` from a NodeJS/MongoDB backend.

What I'm not exactly clear on is how to pass the id attribute into the URI. I've been doing the following from Chrome dev tools:

```
var task = new App.Models.Task({ id: '51c09ae7d3b35d29d4dfdecd' });
task.fetch();
```

And I receive the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/tasks/:_id 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How do I properly set this up?

Here's my Backbone code:

```
(function() {

  window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {}
  };

  App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: '',
      completed: false
    },

    idAttribute: "_id",

    urlRoot: '/tasks/:_id'
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/ for guidance I would say you don't need to define the idAttribute and your urlRoot should just be "/tasks". Backbone should handle the rest.

Note: I haven't used Backbone myself yet but have been reading up on it.

Comment: Evan, Also you should delete this line - idAttribute: "_id"

Comment: Removing `idAttribute: "_id",` worked along with switching urlRoot to `'/tasks/'`. I'm a little confused because I thought that line was necessary due to Mongo using `_id`, not `id`. How does Backbone know to fetch the attribute called `_id` then?

Comment: I don't know the details of your backend but I would expect that "id" is used in the REST API but then when your service connects to Mongo it uses "_id" there.